# API Response header's Content-Type vs Response Value is different - Causing Error

Tags: angular, api, http, content-type

I'm new to Angular and have been working on a project.
I am making an API call which is working perfectly well in Postman. The thing is - Response type is **Text**. Further more in Postman - Content-Type is **text/plain;charset=UTF-8**.

[image: POstman API call response header]

Now, When I'm running the API call using Angular I tried setting the following headers(tried all three of them):

[image: Angular header set]

Fun Fact: I'm getting **200 as response** when running angular code. However, my error section of the code always gets executed.

Here is the request header I'm sending(as captured in the browser):

[image: Browser request header]

And here's the response header:

[image: Browser Response Header]

But here's the catch 22: My response is still **String** and hence following issue rises up:
[image]

1. Am I doing anything wrong? My header setting works out for all other API calls? Can I set the Response header's Content type to my demand?
2. Is it possible that the API response-header's content-type needs to be set?

Comment: Well the API says the response is json. You can convince angular to parse it as text by adding {responseType :’text’} as second (for get requests) or third (for POST) param in your http call.

Comment: @MikeOne If you see in the second pic above, I have tried that already and failed miserably. Is there any other way I can get this done?